# How are the Dow 30 chosen?

Tags: stocks

I'm particularly curious why Google is not included, since their share price towers above all the component prices in the Dow 30.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing a comment about how Apple has a higher price than Google before you linked the other question. I like the note about dividends from JohnFX's answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Dow Jones index methodology](http://www.djindexes.com/mdsidx/downloads/meth_info/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average_Methodology.pdf) notes the construction of the index. [Why Apple, Google are left off Dow Jones industrial average](http://www.chicagobusiness.com/article/20130910/NEWS01/130919979/why-apple-google-are-left-off-dow-jones-industrial-average) has some commentary if you want an answer on those specific companies.